# Number of primary key values passed must match key values defined on the entity

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a table for a user to be in a role, it is only one of two roles that the user can be in.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles] (
    [UserId] INT NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [RoleId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles_dbo.webpages_Roles_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[webpages_Roles] ([RoleId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Roles] (
    [RoleId]                     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [RoleName]                   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [webpages_Membership_UserId] INT            NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.webpages_Roles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RoleId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.webpages_Roles_dbo.webpages_Membership_webpages_Membership_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([webpages_Membership_UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[webpages_Membership] ([UserId])
);
```

In my code I am trying to remove a user from `UsersInRoles` however I keep getting an error back from my tempdata:

> Error occurred with roles.The number of primary key values passed must
>   match number of primary key values defined on the entity. Parameter
>   name: key Values

This is the code I am using:

```
        string pid = form["pid"];

        try
        {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                Provider cprovider = _db.Providers.Find(pid);
                var UserId = cprovider.UserProfileId;


                try
                {
                    webpages_Membership cmembership = _db.webpages_Memberships.Find(UserId);
                    _db.webpages_Memberships.Remove(cmembership);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = "Error occured with membership." + ex.Message;
                }
                try
                {
                    UserProfile cprofile = _db.UserProfiles.Find(UserId);
                    _db.UserProfiles.Remove(cprofile);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = "Error occured with profile." + ex.Message;
                }
                try // this code is causing an exception
                {
                    webpages_UsersInRoles croles = _db.webpages_UsersInRoles.Find(UserId);
                    _db.webpages_UsersInRoles.Remove(croles);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = "Error occured with roles." + ex.Message;
                }


                cprovider.UserProfileId = null;
                cprovider.PendingActivation = null;
                cprovider.Activated = null;
                cprovider.Email = null;


                    _db.Entry(cprovider).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Find` method call is missing a parameter - it requires both `UserId` and `RoleId`:

```
_db.webpages_UsersInRoles.Find(UserId, RoleId)
```

If your goal is to remove all of a user's roles, then don't use the find method, use `Where` w/ `RemoveRange`:

```
var croles = _db.webpages_UsersInRoles.Where( uir => uir.UserId == UserId );
_db.webpages_UsersInRoles.RemoveRange( croles );
```